# How to correctly use Order By with Inner Joins

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, inner-join

I have an SQL statement that looks something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 AS bl  
INNER JOIN table2 AS vbsa ON bl.id=vbsa.businesslisting_id AND vbsa.section_id ='70'  
INNER JOIN table3 AS vbla ON bl.id=vbla.businesslisting_id AND vbla.location_id='1'  
WHERE bl.published = '1' 
ORDER BY bl.listing_type DESC
```

For some reason this will not return any rows, however if I remove the ORDER BY clause it does return rows. Any ideas why this would be?

The column listing_type does exist in the DB and contains number values. It is set as varchar type. I thought maybe this was the problem but I tried a different column (ID) and it still did not work.

Thanks
Robert

Comment: `ORDER BY` is not supposed to filter results, so unless there is a bug in mysql (very unlikely), the number of rows must be the same regardless of `ORDER BY`.  I suggest if you use any gui tool to run queries, make sure it doesn't filter anything.

Comment: Not trying to filter the results just sort them. I agree but it does work if I remove the clause. I have tried table1.listing_type as well, made no difference.

Comment: That a response to my question!?

Comment: No, it's an appropriate comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I have been working on someone else's code and they did not add indexes to the tables in question.

Therefore when I added the sort by attribute and ran the query it was exceeding the MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows.

I added the indexes and now it works perfect.

Thanks for everyones input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM table1 AS bl  
INNER JOIN table2 AS vbsa ON bl.id = vbsa.businesslisting_id
INNER JOIN table3 AS vbla ON bl.id = vbla.businesslisting_id
WHERE bl.published = 1 AND vbsa.section_id = 70 AND vbla.location_id = 1
ORDER BY bl.listing_type DESC
```

Also make sure to view the error messages when debugging SQL, trying to fix without seeing these errors is difficult

Comment: Thanks for the response. Tried your suggestion but getting the error: 104 - The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET SQL_MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay